# Sinatra: form data is missing from the params hash upon submission

Tags: parameters, sinatra, forms, http-post

I’m writing a pretty basic CRUD app in Sinatra (it’s a CRUD app that makes CRUD apps, for what it’s worth). The create functionality works fine, but the update functionality is not working. The controller is not receiving the form data in the params hash. I can see the form data collected in Chrome Dev Tools, but by the time it gets to the controller the params hash looks like `{"splat"=>[], "captures"=>["23"], "id"=>"23"}` instead of, for example, `{"crudapp"=>{"title"=>"Promises", "description"=>"tbd", "model"=>"Promise"}, "columns"=>[{"key_name"=>"name", "data_type"=>"String"}, {"key_name"=>"description", "data_type"=>"String"}, {"key_name"=>"fulfillment", "data_type"=>"Boolean"}]}`. What am I missing? Relevant code below.

edit.erb

```
<div class="entry-header">edit an app</div>
<form method="post" action="/crudapps/<%= @crudapp.id %>">
  <input type="hidden" name="crudapp[user_id]" value="<%= @crudapp.user_id %>">

  <ul class="basic-form">
    <li>
      <label for="crudapp[title]">Application title</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="crudapp[title]" value="<%= @crudapp.title %>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="crudapp[description]">Description</label>
      <textarea name="crudapp[description]"><%= @crudapp.description %></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="crudapp[model]">Item name</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="crudapp[model]" value="<%= @crudapp.model %>">
    </li>

    <input type="hidden" name="columns[0][id]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[0].id %>">

    <li>
      <label for="columns[][key_name]">First attribute name</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="columns[0][key_name]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[0].key_name %>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="columns[0][data_type]">First attribute data type</label>
      <select name="columns[0][data_type]">
        <option value="String" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[0].data_type=='String' %>>String</option>
        <option value="Number" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[0].data_type=='Number' %>>Number</option>
        <option value="Date" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[0].data_type=='Date' %>>Date</option>
        <option value="Boolean" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[0].data_type=='Boolean' %>>Boolean</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <input type="hidden" name="columns[1][id]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[1].id %>">

    <li>
      <label for="columns[][key_name]">Second attribute name</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="columns[1][key_name]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[1].key_name %>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="columns[1][data_type]">Second attribute data type</label>
      <select name="columns[1][data_type]">
        <option value="String" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[1].data_type=='String' %>>String</option>
        <option value="Number" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[1].data_type=='Number' %>>Number</option>
        <option value="Date" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[1].data_type=='Date' %>>Date</option>
        <option value="Boolean" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[1].data_type=='Boolean' %>>Boolean</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <input type="hidden" name="columns[2][id]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[2].id %>">

    <li>
      <label for="columns[][key_name]">Third attribute name</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="columns[][key_name]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[2].key_name %>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="columns[2][data_type]">Third attribute data type</label>
      <select name="columns[2][data_type]">
        <option value="String" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[2].data_type=='String' %>>String</option>
        <option value="Number" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[2].data_type=='Number' %>>Number</option>
        <option value="Date" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[2].data_type=='Date' %>>Date</option>
        <option value="Boolean" <%= 'selected' if @crudapp.columns[2].data_type=='Boolean' %>>Boolean</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="crudapp[github]">GitHub link</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="crudapp[github]" value="<%= @crudapp.github %>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="crudapp[web]">Web link</label>
      <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="crudapp[web]" value="<%= @crudapp.web %>">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="entry-submit-margin">
    <input class="entry-submit" type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

   # lots of other routes omitted

   post "/crudapps/:id" do
     if logged_in?
       @crudapp = Crudapp.find(params[:id])
       if current_user.id == @crudapp.user_id
         if !params[:crudapp] # This data is absent, so we always land here.
           flash[:message] = "edit functionality is down!"
         else
           @crudapp.update(params[:crudapp])
           params[:columns].each do |params_column|
             column = Column.find_or_create_by(id: params_column[:id])
             @crudapp.columns << @column.update(params_column)
           end
         end
         redirect "/crudapps/#{@crudapp.id}"
       else
         flash[:message] = "you must be the app's creator to edit"
         redirect "/crudapps"
       end
     else
       flash[:message] = "please log in to edit an app"
       redirect "/login"
     end
   end 
end
```

Comment: Ok the answer is that I left out an array index (2) in the name field of one of the input tags. I'll post an answer to the question, though, because it seems to point to a broader question, and because maybe someone else will have a broken params hash problem and will see this here positive outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recapping our solution from the Slack chat!

There is an index missing in this part of the HTML:

```
<li>
  <label for="columns[][key_name]">Third attribute name</label>
  <input class="fieldbox" type="text" name="columns[][key_name]" value="<%= @crudapp.columns[2].key_name %>">
</li>
```

The name attribute of the input tag should be `columns[2][key_name]` (it’s missing the 2). This causes the query parameter string to become unparseable, so Rack assumes it's some kind of binary or non-standard format and passes it to the handler as `request.body` instead.

I wrote a simple Rack app to echo the params back to the requester, and used curl to send the request payload with and without the 2:

```
$ curl --data-raw 'crudapp%5Buser_id%5D=1&crudapp%5Btitle%5D=Conundrum&crudapp%5Bdescription%5D=It%27s+uber+for+problem-solving%21%21%21+friend&crudapp%5Bmodel%5D=Problem&columns%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=85&columns%5B0%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=summary&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&columns%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=86&columns%5B1%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=pros-and-cons&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&columns%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=87&columns%5B%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=solution&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&crudapp%5Bgithub%5D=&crudapp%5Bweb%5D=' localhost:4567
{}
$ curl --data-raw 'crudapp%5Buser_id%5D=1&crudapp%5Btitle%5D=Conundrum&crudapp%5Bdescription%5D=It%27s+uber+for+problem-solving%21%21%21+friend&crudapp%5Bmodel%5D=Problem&columns%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=85&columns%5B0%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=summary&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&columns%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=86&columns%5B1%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=pros-and-cons&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&columns%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=87&columns%5B2%5D%5Bkey_name%5D=solution&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata_type%5D=String&crudapp%5Bgithub%5D=&crudapp%5Bweb%5D=' localhost:4567
{"crudapp"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "title"=>"Conundrum", "description"=>"It's uber for problem-solving!!! friend", "model"=>"Problem", "github"=>"", "web"=>""}, "columns"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"85", "key_name"=>"summary", "data_type"=>"String"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"86", "key_name"=>"pros-and-cons", "data_type"=>"String"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"87", "key_name"=>"solution", "data_type"=>"String"}}}
```

Hope this helps!